# create a custom shape layout for a child widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can we create a constraint that wraps around a Text widget with long text and the text get its parent shape. For example look at this image:
[image]

I've used chatGBP and it suggested this solution but did not work as expected.

1. Create a custom widget that extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget. This widget will be responsible for rendering the triangle shape.
2. Implement a custom RenderObject that extends RenderBox. This render object will handle the painting of the triangle shape.
3. Override the paint method in the custom RenderObject to define the shape and style of the triangle.
4. Create a custom widget that extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget to wrap the long text. This widget will use the custom render object to display the triangle shape.
5. Use the Wrap widget to wrap the long text widget inside the custom widget.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TriangleTextWrapper extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  TriangleTextWrapper({Key? key, required Widget child}) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return RenderTriangleTextWrapper();
  }
}

class RenderTriangleTextWrapper extends RenderBox with RenderObjectWithChildMixin<RenderBox>{
  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    final size = constraints.biggest;
    final path = Path();
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..strokeWidth = 2;

    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width / 2, size.height);
    path.close();

    context.canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool get sizedByParent => true;

  @override
  void performResize() {
    size = constraints.biggest;
  }
}

// Usage
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: TriangleTextWrapper(
            child: Text(
              'This is a long text that will be wrapped in a triangle shape.',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you cannot do that, sorry

Comment: @pskink are we sure? chatGBP suggested a solution but it was not complete so I decided to ask here.

Comment: Could you share both what ChatGTP suggested, where you've looked / what you've tried already, and what it is you're trying to achieve overall? I'm thinking there may be a better approach to your problem :)

Comment: @dwb I've shared that solution.

Comment: chatGBP is wrong, you can't do that unless you implement a custom text layout algorithm (now it supports a "fixed width" column only)